# Getting Helm to default to the shortest match

Tags: helm

Is there any way of getting Helm to default to the shortest match? In many cases the way Helm works at the moment (unless I have some weird configuration) is inferior to vanilla Emacs in many cases.

An example... I want to invoke "revert-buffer".

In standard Emacs it's 9 keystrokes:

```
M-x revert <tab> <return>
```

In Helm mode it's 13:

```
M-x revert-b C-n C-n C-n <return>.
```

...although if it was set to default to the shortest match (which makes sense, Occam's razor, right?) it would be something like 8:

```
M-x rev buf <return>
```

Comment: I get 5 keystrokes with `smex` and `flx-ido-mode`: C-t rb C-n RET.

Comment: But with Helm you get 6 keystrokes and key binding for the command available. It is already my favorite for executing command and learn a key binding at the same time, so you don't repeat yourself with: looking up the key binding (`C-h f` then type the command then `RET`) and executing the command (`M-x` then type the command then `RET`); if you are lucky you still have to press the key binding to execute that command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `helm-M-x`. It is not bound to `M-x` by default, so you have to do it yourself:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)
```

with `helm-M-x`, I only need to type `re buf` to get `revert-buffer` as the first match.

You can learn more about Helm in [this guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html).

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed fix it, although I don't understand why the default M-x doesn't default to the shortest match.

Comment: Because the default `M-x` runs `execute-extended-command`, which is vanilla `M-x` with Helm interface. `helm-M-x` is an entirely different command. You see more goodis in `helm-M-x`, such as key binding of each command if available and `C-z` to see the description of each command.

Comment: With  helm-M-x-fuzzy-match set to true, it's enough with M-x rvb...